# MS ACCESS - Max (Strength) grouping issue

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I have an Access Database which has a table that has the following fields:
     Drug_Code, Drug_Label, Alt_Drug_Code, Alt_Drug_Label, Strength, Alt_Drug_Code_10

I am needing to perform a query that gets the max(Strength) based off of the Alt_Drug_Code_10, but then return all of the other fields.
Problem I am having is The Alt_Drug_Code will have multiple codes within the Alt_Drug_code_10 which also has multiple labels within the Alt_Drug_Label.

I thought I could do a First on the Order by; but that doesn't seem to be getting me what I need.  Here is what the table looks like.

```
 Drug_Code         Drug_Label     Alt_Drug_Code    Alt_Drug_Label  Strength   Alt_Drug_Code_10 
12345678912345      Drug1        54321987654321      AltDrug1          1          5432198765
12345678912345      Drug1        54321987654341      AltDrug1          5          5432198765
12345678912345      Drug1        98765432101234      AltDrug2          50         9876543210
12345678912345      Drug1        54545454540002      AltDrug3          50         5454545454
12345678912345      Drug1        54545454540001      AltDrug3          100        5454545454 
12345678912345      Drug1        54545454540003      AltDrug3          150        5454545454
12345678912345      Drug1        54545454540004      AltDrug3          200        5454545454
12345678912345      Drug1        54545454540004      AltDrug3 E2       200        5454545454
12345678912345      Drug1        54545454540004      AltDrug3 E3       200        5454545454
```

So For AltDrug1 I would only expect to see 1 line in my result with Max(Strength) = 5
For AltDrug2 it's good/correct.
For AltDrug3 it gets a little more complicated. I would only want to see 1 line in the end with Max(Strength) = 200 ; and it wouldn't matter which Alt_Drug_Label it chooses, could be first, last; just as long as it is Max(Strength) = 200.

Here is my query so far:
`SELECT DL.DRUG_CODE, DL.DRUG_LABEL, DL.ALT_DRUG_CODE, DL.ALT_DRUG_LABEL, MAX(DL.STRENGTH), DL.ALT_DRUG_CODE_10 
FROM DRUG_LIST DL
GROUP BY DL.DRUG_CODE, DL.DRUG_LABEL, DL.ALT_DRUG_CODE, DL.ALT_DRUG_LABEL`

Comment: Use a sub query to get the max alt_drug_code then join it back to the base query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this will work in later versions of Access but I'm not completely sure:

```
SELECT
    DL.DRUG_CODE, DL.DRUG_LABEL, DL.ALT_DRUG_CODE, DL.ALT_DRUG_LABEL,
    DL.ALT_DRUG_CODE_10,
    (
        SELECT MAX(DL.STRENGTH)
        FROM DRUG_LIST DL2
        WHERE DL2.ALT_DRUG_CODE_10 = DL.ALT_DRUG_CODE_10
    ) MAX_STRENGTH
FROM DRUG_LIST DL
GROUP BY
    DL.DRUG_CODE, DL.DRUG_LABEL, DL.ALT_DRUG_CODE, DL.ALT_DRUG_LABEL
```

I just did some searching of the web on "ms access scalar subquery" and couldn't find any examples of subqueries in the select clause. I did find a weird notation for subqueries with square brackets and terminated by a period that is completely unfamiliar to me.

**EDIT**:
After reading your comments on xQbert's answer I think this may be what you were after.

```
SELECT *
FROM DRUG_LIST DL
WHERE STRENGTH = (
    SELECT MAX(STRENGTH)
    FROM DRUG_LIST DL2
    WHERE DL2.ALT_DRUG_CODE_10 = DL.ALT_DRUG_CODE_10
)
```

Answer (score 0):

in this case generating a subset of drugs grouped by drug_code_10 returning the max value, and then joining back to your superset data seems like it would do the job...

```
SELECT DL.DRUG_CODE, DL.DRUG_LABEL, DL.ALT_DRUG_CODE, 
       max(DL.ALT_DRUG_LABEL), DL.STRENGTH, DL.ALT_DRUG_CODE_10 
FROM DRUG_LIST DL
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT max(DL.Strength) mStr, alt_drug_Code_10 
    FROM drug_list 
    GROUP BY alt_drug_Code_10) B
 on DL.Strength = B.mStr and B.Alt_Drug_code_10 = Dl.Alt_drug_Code_10
GROUP BY DL.DRUG_CODE, DL.ALT_DRUG_CODE, DL.ALT_DRUG_LABEL, dl.strength
```

Comment: Thank you! that works great!  Only thing is that the Alt_Drug_Label is still returning multiple like my example with Alt_Drug_Labels AltDrug3 E3 & AltDrug3 E2;  I am getting the 3 rows returned with AltDrug3, AltDrug3 E2 & AltDrug3 E3

Comment: I decided to go with SQL; I exported the data into a SQL table and had a much simpler time getting what I needed. Thanks for your help! Much appreciated.

Comment: Which alt_Drug_Label do you want returned?  we can alter the select to return max and group by since the str will be duplicated.